# Strange behaviour of bash script using tr

Tags: linux, bash, glob, tr

I have legacy script where tr command is used and on some servers(I have no idea what are the differences) such command

```
echo ABCD | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

works incorrectly - the second argument is passed like just **a** not the **[a-z]**
and if I quote all arguments - it works fine:

```
echo ABCD | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
```

Moreover the incorrect behaviour is seen if only command is executed by root, other users do not suffer from this error.

Tell me plz what is the reason of this behaviour.

**UPD**

```
ls -l [A-Z] [a-z]
ls: cannot access [A-Z]: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4870 Mar  2  2018 a
```

Comment: are you saying `echo ABCD | tr [A-Z] [a-z]` works correctly when executed by non-root users?

Comment: You have a file named `a` in the working directory, don't you?

Comment: Both commands work just fine on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: would you run `echo $SHELL` to see what shell each user uses

Comment: Please add output of `ls -l [A-Z] [a-z]` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus in fact the file named **a** do exists in the current dir where the command is tested

Comment: You don't need brackets there by the way, `tr A-Z a-z` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is a translate command on linux. And the two arguments should be strings to represent "kinda regex" selection.

According to `man tr`:

> tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

> SETs are specified as strings of characters

So

```
echo ABCD | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
```

is replacing all capital letters with their corresponding small letters.

```
echo ABCD | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

does not work because the regex are presented as a linux command, and your shell tries to run them.

**Edit**:
Both commands work on bash. But only the quoted one works on zsh. So it might be the case that root and other users use a different shell interpreter. would you please use `echo $SHELL` to check which shell a user is using.

Comment: I know, but why the first [A-Z] is passed as is even if it is not quoted? And on some servers(maybe they have more modern bash) there is no error at all